# Inherit Page class in a .cs file in App_Code folder when Application as a New Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is the code i have in a cs file and placed in App_Code folder.

```
public class ABC: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ABC()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
}
```

Here i am able to inherit the 'Page class' to 'ABC class' when the solution was taken as "New Website" and not able to inherit when solution taken as "New Project".

Is this the problem due to the type of solution(New Project/New Website)?

Comment: Use "Add New Project", but then don't use App_Code. It's pretty much just for web site "projects".

Comment: Thats Ok. Then whats the way to inherit page class in a cs file when solution as "New Project" instead "New Website"?

Comment: You have to add a reference to `System.Web` in the project, and then add `using System.Web.UI;` - then you can inherit from `Page`.  But why would you want (or need) to do that in a non-web application?

Comment: And what type of project are you creating? Console, Class Library, etc.

Comment: Its a website project only but the way i have created the project if File>New Project>Asp.Net Web Application instead of File>New Website.

Comment: You should not use Web Site projects unless you have to. They've very unusual. Anytime someone asks on [so] about some basic feature and why it's not working, I ask, "are you using a web site project"? That's usually why the feature doesn't work.

Comment: Hint: as a test, create a new web application project somewhere, and look at the default.aspx and default.aspx.cs files.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a web site and a web application (at least as far as Visual Studio is concerned) is that a web application contains a DLL, where as a web site takes the code in App_Code and compiles it on the fly.

The bottom line is that if you create a web application, you shouldn't use App_Code.  If you create a web site, then you should.

Comment: Thats fine. I have used the namespace "System.Web.UI" in the cs file but not able to inherit page class to the class "ABC" i have mentioned in my question. Whats the way to make it possible in web application? (I have removed App_Code folder and placed that cs file in another folder)

Comment: If the project is a Web Application, then it should already have the `System.Web` reference.   Since you mention removing the `App_Code` folder, it sounds like you created a web site project - but that should still have the necessary references already.  Try creating a new Web Application project and look at the default pages as @JohnSaunders suggested above in the comments.